# ACL always sets group execute permissions on files (Samba)

Tags: samba, chmod, acl, chown, setfacl

I have some users in the "sambashare" group and some in the "sambashareAdmin" group.
Only users from the "sambashareAdmin" group are alowed to change/create stuff.

All files should belong to haegarthehorrible:sambashare.
No matter if I create them on the server or if I move/copy them to the server.

The problem is that all files get execute permissions on the group (670/-rw-rwx---) and not 660/-rw-rw----
if the Windows workstation user (paradise) does it.

I tried "obey pam restrictions" with yes and no in samba what makes no difference.
I also tried "create mask" and "directory mask" or "force create mode and "force directory mode"
or both together.

I tried chmod g+s and g+s,u+s.

I tried complicated stuff like:

```
~$ sudo chmod -R a-x,u=rX,g=rX,u+w,g+w /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
~$ sudo chmod -R a-x,u=rwX,g=rwX /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
```

And also funny ist that if I use "rwX" instead of "rw" (chmod or setfacl) I get execute on the owner permissions.
I thought X does only set it on directories?

So here is what now looks really complicated and still does not work. Remember this are all directories that already have files/directories in it.

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
   server string = Harvester
   server role = standalone server
   server min protocol = SMB2
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   interfaces = lo enp0s31f6
   bind interfaces only = yes
   logging = file
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   load printers = no
   show add printer wizard = no
   disable netbios = yes
   dns proxy = no
   deadtime = 30
   smb ports = 445
   smb encrypt = off
   security = user
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   use sendfile = yes
   directory mask = 2750
   create mask = 0640
   access based share enum = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   guest account = shareguest

[Backup]
   path = /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
   guest ok = no
   browseable = no
   create mask = 0660
   directory mask = 2770
   force group = sambashare
   force user = haegarthehorrible
   write list = @sambashareAdmin
   valid users = haegarthehorrible paradise
   inherit acls = Yes
```

Set Permissions:

```
~$ sudo chown -R haegarthehorrible:sambashare /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
~$ sudo setfacl -R -b -k -n /mnt/pool/Share/Backup                         # Remove ACL
~$ sudo chmod -R g+s,u+s /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
~$ sudo chmod 0770 /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
~$ sudo find /mnt/pool/Share/Backup -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
~$ sudo find /mnt/pool/Share/Backup -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
~$ sudo setfacl -R -d -m u::rw,g::rw,u:haegarthehorrible:rw,g:sambashareAdmin:rw /mnt/pool/Share/Backup  # ACL for new items
~$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:haegarthehorrible:rw,g:sambashareAdmin:rw /mnt/pool/Share/Backup                 # ACL for old/existing items
```

sambashareAdmin Members:

```
~$ members sambashareAdmin
haegarthehorrible paradise
```

sambashare Members:

```
~$ members sambashare
shareguest watcher
```

Share Root Folder Permissions:

```
~$ ls -ld /mnt/pool/Share
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug  7  2023 /mnt/pool/Share

~$ stat /mnt/pool/Share
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (0/root)  Gid: (0/root)

~$ getfacl /mnt/pool/Share
# file: mnt/pool/Share
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Share Permissions:

```
~$ ls -ld /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
drwsrws---+ 5 haegarthehorrible sambashare 4096 Apr 25  2022 /mnt/pool/Share/Backup

~$ stat /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
Access: (6770/drwsrws---)  Uid: (1000/haegarthehorrible)  Gid: (996/sambashare)

~$ getfacl /mnt/pool/Share/Backup
# file: mnt/pool/Share/Backup
# owner: haegarthehorrible
# group: sambashare
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rw-
default:user:haegarthehorrible:rw-
default:group::rw-
default:group:sambashareAdmin:rw-
default:mask::rw-
default:other::---
```

File Permissions:

```
~$ ls -l /mnt/pool/Share/Backup/Test.txt
-rw-rwx---+ 1 haegarthehorrible sambashare 0 Feb 11 07:18 /mnt/pool/Share/Backup/Test.txt

~$ stat /mnt/pool/Share/Backup/Test.txt
Access: (0670/-rw-rwx---)  Uid: (1000/haegarthehorrible)  Gid: (996/sambashare)

~$ getfacl /mnt/pool/Share/Backup/Test.txt
# file: mnt/pool/Share/Backup/Test.txt
# owner: haegarthehorrible
# group: sambashare
user::rw-
user:haegarthehorrible:rw-
group::rw-
group:sambashare:rw-
group:sambashareAdmin:rw-
mask::rwx
other::---
```